# Lack of Benching Rosh Chodesh Tishrei

Tags: minhag, rosh-hashanah-new-year, rosh-chodesh-new-month

I have heard that the reason we do not Bench Rosh Chodesh Tishrei is in order to confuse the Satan. Now the Satan is no fool. How is the Satan getting confused when we pull this trick year after year?

Comment: I actually heard that the reason is because Hashem himself bentches this month.

Comment: @yydl It's a famous vort of the Baal Shem Tov

Comment: @yydl: see page 4 of https://www.colelchabad.org/assets/pdfs/Elul_English.pdf : _The
Alter Rebbe said in the name of the Baal Shem
Tov: “Tishrei is blessed by the Holy One, blessed be
He, Himself. And with the power of this blessing, the
Jews bless the other eleven months of the year_